# Trying to forecast the next 24hrs temperature using UCI repository datasets in R programming

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

Hi I accessed the datasets from the UCI repository http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Air+Quality

I am trying to predict the next 24hrs temperature.Below is the code which I have written

### filling the missing values by NA

```
library(plyr)
AirQualityUCI[AirQualityUCI==-200.0]<-NA
```

### Replacing the NA by mean of each columns

```
for(i in 1:ncol(AirQualityUCI)){
 AirQualityUCI[is.na(AirQualityUCI[,i]),i] <- mean(AirQualityUCI[,i], na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

### plot time series

```
plot(AirQualityUCI$T, type = "l")
```

### How do I set the frequency in hours and predict the temperature of next 24hrs ?

```
Tempts <- ts(AirQualityUCI)
Temprforecasts <- HoltWinters(Tempts, beta=FALSE, gamma=FALSE)
library(forecast)
accuracy(Temprforecasts,24)
```

Getting the below error

```
Error in attr(x, "tsp") <- value : 
  invalid time series parameters specified
```

Comment: which variable are you forecasting?

Comment: @pyll I am trying to forecast the Temperature(T) 12th column in the dataset for the next 24hrs. Should I reorder the dataset so that temperature column will come at the end of the dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(readxl)
AirQualityUCI <- read_excel("AirQualityUCI.xlsx") 

library(plyr)
AirQualityUCI[AirQualityUCI==-200.0]<-NA

#First, limit to the one column you are interested in (make sure data is sorted by time variable before doing this)
library(data.table)
temp <- setDT(AirQualityUCI)[,c("T")]

#Replace NA with mean
temp$T <- ifelse(is.na(temp$T), mean(temp$T, na.rm=TRUE), temp$T)

#Create time series object...in this case freq = 365 * 24 (hours in year)
Tempts <- ts(temp, frequency = 365*24)

#Model
Temprforecasts <- HoltWinters(Tempts, beta = FALSE, gamma = FALSE)

#Generate next 24 hours forecast
library(forecast)
output.forecast <- forecast.HoltWinters(Temprforecasts, h = 24)
```

Comment: If you use AirQualityUCI.xlsx you won't be facing any problem. If you extract .csv fromat you will get the problem. I am not facing any problem with temprature T

Comment: # Importing the datasets 
library(readxl)
AirQualityUCI <- read_excel("C:/AirQualityUCI/AirQualityUCI.xlsx")
View(AirQualityUCI)